# Jersey RESTful Web Service Connection Refused

Tags: java, rest, maven, jersey, connection-refused

I am trying to run a Jersey server on my local OS X machine.

So far, I have executed these three commands as per the Jersey website instruction:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=jersey-quickstart-grizzly2 \
-DarchetypeGroupId=org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes -DinteractiveMode=false \
-DgroupId=com.example -DartifactId=simple-service -Dpackage=com.example \
-DarchetypeVersion=2.14

mvn clean test

mvn exec:java
```

It appears to be working fine, in that the last command prints this:

```
Dec 17, 2014 12:05:15 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.NetworkListener start
INFO: Started listener bound to [localhost:8080]
Dec 17, 2014 12:05:15 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer start
INFO: [HttpServer] Started.
Jersey app started with WADL available at http://localhost:8080/myapp/application.wadl
Hit enter to stop it...
```

However, when trying to call `http://localhost:8080` in the browser, I get an address unreachable error. I have also tested it with telnet:

```
telnet localhost 8080
```

Which returns a connection refused error. Clearly, the Jersey servlet "thinks" it's listening locally on port 8080, but it's definitely not. I have tried reaching it using `127.0.0.1` instead of localhost, and I have tried running Jersey on a different port. Nothing seems to be able to fix it.

I'm running Jersey 2.1.4 with Maven 3.2.3 on OS X 10.10 and using Java 1.8.0.

EDIT: There is no firewall blocking incoming connections. I have turned it off to eliminate that possibility.

Comment: Sounds like you have a firewall blocking the server socket.

Comment: No, I don't. Turning off the firewall was the first thing I did to make sure it was not the reason. Sorry for not adding that in my question.

Comment: Post the output of `netstat -tlp`.

Comment: `$ netstat -tlp`
> `netstat: option requires an argument -- p`

Comment: Does the unit test work? There should be a test (in the test package) you can run

Comment: Yes, coincidentally, the test passes perfectly fine.

Comment: Hmm, that's weird because the test actually runs the server in the main class and accesses the same url you are attempting in the browser

Comment: Dumb question, but do you _stop_ the server by pressing enter?

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure of the netstat syntax for BSD.

Comment: @peeskillet Haha :D but no, I don't.

Comment: @chrylis I'm running OS X Yosemite, actually.

Comment: @arik OS X is a BSD.

Comment: Whoops, you're right @chrylis. I only had FreeBSD in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok guys, I have found the solution.

The default base URI is `http://localhost:8080/myapp`. You can see it in `Main.java`, in line 16:

```
public static final String BASE_URI = "http://localhost:8080/myapp/";
```

I changed `localhost` to `0.0.0.0`, and it worked!

```
public static final String BASE_URI = "http://0.0.0.0:8080/myapp/";
```

Thank you very much for your help, and I am sorry that I ended up answering my own question. I hope it helps some people in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need to use the glassfish stack: I prefer archetype

`com.sun.jersey.archetypes:jersey-quickstart-webapp`

with jetty:

replace in the plugins section of your pom the glassfish plugin with

`<plugin>
         <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
         <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>9.2.2.v20140723</version>
      </plugin>`

Now you can run the rest service with `mvn jetty:run`

good luck

Comment: Thanks for the tip! As it happens, Jersey is part of the spec so I cannot use your solution. But perhaps some other poor soul will find this helpful ;)

Comment: @arik My solutions still uses Jersey, just the server that runs it (for test) is different (jetty iso glassfish)